# Movement of a dynamic body up a slope using box2d

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

I am new to android development and as my first attempt at getting a working android app I'm trying to make a 2D side scrolling game (somewhat similar to Mario), using libGDX and box2d.

I found this tutorial to get me up and running: [Libgdx Box2d Tiled Maps](http://dpk.net/2011/05/01/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/#p1). Which I've followed (and made a few changes to) and I've got it up and running with my own set of tiles. The problem I'm having is that when my box (called jumper in the example) reaches the bottom of a sloped tile, it simply stops moving. If you download the example for part 2 and modify the collisions.txt file and change line 12 to be 0x31,31x0 and walk to the first slope you should hopefully see my problem (the example doesn't attempt to handle sloped collisions). I'm certain my collision boundaries are correct as I've got debug rendering switched on and I can see them in the correct place.

From the research I've been doing on the internet and from playing around with the code there may be a couple of solutions:

1. I've tried changing the centre of mass for the box object to lower down and setting fixed rotation to false (jumper.sexFixedRotation(false)) so that the box angles with the slope and the linear impulse is applied with respect to the plane. I've been unable to get this working.
2. I've tried detecting horizontal and vertical velocity and applying a different linear impulse if the box is not moving but an input is still being pressed.

   ```
       if (moveRight && !moveLeft) {

         if(!(Math.abs(jumper.getLinearVelocity().x) > 0.0f) && !(Math.abs(jumper.getLinearVelocity().y) > 0.00f)) {
           jumper.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.09f), jumper.getWorldCenter());
       } else {
           jumper.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.05f, 0.0f), jumper.getWorldCenter());
       }
       if (!jumperFacingRight) {
           jumperSprite.flip(true, false);
           jumperFacingRight = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   This does work, but is incredibly slow and jumpy (not to mention hacky!).

I'm sure there is something that I'm missing/not thinking of and any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Is it a friction issue? What do you get if you make the friction of your player fixture zero?

Comment: Thanks for the response iforce.

If I make the friction zero the interaction with the slope is the same just the sprite moves faster along the flats (as one would expect).

I forgot to mention that if the sprite is jumped onto the slope and a single linear impulse is applied down the slope, then the sprite slides down the slope as you would expect.

Comment: Is it possible that your sideways force is too weak? For example even when friction is zero, if the sideways force was exactly the same magnitude as gravity then the two forces would exactly cancel out on a 45 degree slope.

Comment: That isn't the issue. To confirm I set friction to zero and gravity to 1.0f and applied a linear impulse of 2.0f and it still just stops dead at the bottom of the slope. Could it be something to do with no upward force being applied?

Comment: Weird. Is it only when the character approaches the slope, or at any point on it? I'm just wondering if he is getting caught on the bottom corner of it - you could check by making the sloped tile a little lower to be sure the character is not tripping on the beginning of the slope.

Comment: It's at any point on the slope. I've tried decreasing the incline and I'm still coming across the same problem. I've come up with a solution of modelling to sprite body as a circle instead of a box and that works. But that way the body doesn't match up to the sprite image.